# Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1 when archiving

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

Below is the error screenshot. Build will always fail.

[image]

Comment: delete your driveddata & clean your project and build again.

Comment: I think it is code signing issue, Check your certificates and all and make sure if everything is alright.

Comment: I've already deleted the previous provisioning profile and tried reinstalling.

However, Im going to delete derived data